# Pandas Pivot Table add subsequent columns then divide by previous column

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have the following pandas pivot table:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'group', columns = 'levels',
                       values = 'uid', aggfunc = 'count', margins = True)
```

There are three levels (level 1, level 2, and level 3).

Basically I have individuals that progress through these levels, but I want to know what percentage of people make it from one level to the next.

I'm thinking I need two transformations:

1. Add subsequent columns so I know how many people made it to each level (i.e. level 1 = level 1 + level 2 + level 3; level 2 = level 2 + level 3; level 3 = level 3)
2. Then divide each column by the previous column to know what percentage of people progressed from the previous level (i.e. level 1 = level 1 / level 1; level 2 = level 2 / level 1; level 3 = level 3 / level 2

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Initial table:

| Groups | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GroupA | 5 | 6 | 3 |
| GroupB | 3 | 2 | 4 |

Want to end up with table:

| Groups | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GroupA | 100% | 64% | 33% |
| GroupB | 100% | 67% | 67% |

Comment: Can you explain the `11%` at `GroupA, Level3`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for that catch! It should be 33%

Comment: Is it possible to see an increasing number of people when moving from one level to another?

Comment: @Vitalizzare Yes because it's not cumulative. For instance, the 3rd grade class might be bigger than the 2nd grade class. Although the 3rd grade class probably isn't bigger than last year's 2nd grade class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logic, you can just take the cumsum in reverse order by the rows, then divide:

```
d = df.iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1).iloc[:,::-1]   
d.div(d.shift(axis=1)).fillna(1)
```

output:

```
        Level 1   Level 2   Level 3
Groups                             
GroupA      1.0  0.642857  0.333333
GroupB      1.0  0.666667  0.666667
```

Comment: Amazing. I still need to take a moment to understand the steps but it looks like it works and the kind of solution I was looking for! Thank you!